# Get individual digits from an Int without using strings?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, numbers, int

I know you can convert the Int to a string and get the digit at position x using the indexer as if it was a char array, but this conversion becomes a bit of an overhead when you're dealing with multiple large numbers.

Is there a way to retrieve a digit at position x without converting the number to a string?

EDIT:

Thank you all, I will benchmark the proposed methods and check if it is any better than converting to a string. Thread will stay unanswered for 24h in case anyone has better ideas.

EDIT 2:

After some simple tests on ulong numbers, I have concluded that converting to strings and extracting the digit can be up to 50% slower compared to the methods provided below, see approved answer.

Comment: Mathmatically it is possible, but I think that will not be less over head than converting it to string

Comment: You could shift and convert the shifted value to a char.

Comment: @sino: I'd definitely expect it to be less overhead than converting it to a string. After all, the conversion to a string needs to do all the same operations *and* construct the string object. Additionally, if only a single digit is required, the OP can stop when they've reached that digit.

Comment: @sino: What gives you that idea? A few simple mathematical operations will require a whole lot less overhead (CPU and memory resources) than generating the string representation of a large number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
int ith_digit(int n, int i) {
    return (int) (n / pow(10, i)) % 10;
}
```

We can get the ith digit by reducing the number down to a point where that digit we want becomes in the one's place, example:

Let's say you wanted the third digit in 12345, then by reducing it to 123 (by dividing it by 10 i number of times) we can then take the remainder of that number divided by ten to get the last digit, which is the digit we wanted.

Comment: This is the solution to the problem. If you provide more explanation of how this works, you'll likely get more up votes.

Comment: @JimMischel I added the explanation Jim, thanks for reminding me!